# HTML Form - Checkbox Replace with Current Date if AJAX Request Successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that includes a checkbox that when clicked performs an AJAX request to update a backend database. I would like to then remove the checkbox input and replace it with a a simple table cell showing the current date.

Here's my form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='dateReceived']").change(function() {
    var recid = $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
    // Create a reference to $(this) here:
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('updateAsset.php', {
      type: 'updateAsset',
      recid: recid,
      dateReceived: dateReceived
    }, function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log( data );
      if (data.error) {
        var ajaxError = (data.text);
        var errorAlert = 'There was an error updating the Date Received - ' + ajaxError + '. Please contact the Help Desk';
        $this.closest('td').addClass("error");
        //display AJAX error details
        $("#dateReceivedErrorMessage").html(errorAlert);
        $("#dateReceivedError").show();
        return; // stop executing this function any further
      } else {
        $this.closest('td').addClass("success")
        $this.closest('td').removeClass("error");
        // if you want to show a success alert enable the following
        // $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-success").html(data.text);
      }

    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
      var ajaxError = 'There was an error updating the Date Received - AJAX request error. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus + '. Please contact the Help Desk';
      // console.log( 'ajaxError: '+ajaxError );
      $this.closest('td').addClass("error");
      //display AJAX error details
      $("#dateReceivedErrorMessage").html(ajaxError);
      $("#dateReceivedError").show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">ID</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Code</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" scope="col">Received</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>


    <tr class="" id="111202">
      <td>GRP423423</td>
      <td>BWEQRQEW/A</td>
      <td>Standard Containers</td>
      <td id="111202"><input type="checkbox" id="111202" value="1" class="form-control" name="dateReceived"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="" id="111216">
      <td>GRP424213412</td>
      <td>PPUPJHL/A</td>
      <td>Packaging Boxes</td>
      <td id="111202"><input type="checkbox" id="111202" value="1" class="form-control" name="dateReceived"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

which is currently working fine and adding the success/danger class accordingly. If it is successful I would like to extend this to replace the checkbox input with a simple table cell showing the current date, e.g.

DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: If you have your date already (DD/MM/YYY)... Then simply use `$this.html(--The date here--)` in your success callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by adding this into your success function:

```
$(this).hide(); 
var dd = new Date();
$(this).closest('td').append(dd.getDate() + '/'+ ('0' + (dd.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/'+ dd.getFullYear());
```

I Think you can change your td's html instead of appending to achieve it

```
$(this).hide(); 
var dd = new Date();
$(this).closest('td').html(dd.getDate() + '/'+ ('0' + (dd.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/'+ dd.getFullYear());
```

Comment: The variable you defined as `dd` but you outputting it as `d`; also I think you should add 1 to `getMonth()` method.

Comment: A `$.post()` is used... which is async. `$(this)` will be undefined. OP uses `$this = $(this);`... So just change `$(this)` for `$this` in your answer ;)

Comment: This is almost there - it's appending the date to the checkbox input but I would like to replace the checkbox input with just the date alone. Is this possible?

Comment: `$this.closest("td")...` will select the cell.